# Change position of div onClick using CSS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how can I change attributes of a div `onClick`.

To make myself clear, I want to know how can I make a div that looks like the one on the [Mozilla Developer Network site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

When you click the "Mozilla" button, the banner slides down to reveal behind it a hidden div.

[image]

I know this hiding thing is based on the `z-index` of the overlapping slide and the absolute position.

My question is how can I make the div slide position (e.g. `top: 0px` to `top: 150px`) and stay there when removing finger from mouse.

Thank you folks.

Comment: Can you show the code that you've got so far...?

Comment: I agree with LinkinTED, can you show us what you've done? You may need to use jQuery, jQuery UI, .click, .on, .animate, etc.

Comment: .click(), .css(), google.

Comment: Clearly shown in http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp
For your best, Just google it and "LEARN TRYING"

Comment: Thank you a lot everyone for you advices and for showing me the right track to search and teach my self about it.

Comment: please tell me how to post my code here. iam kinda new

Comment: Just copy/paste your code into the original post, select entire code text and click `{ }` icon

Comment: @EugineJoseph Please do not advocate using of W3schools - it's very faulty.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I am really sorry for that. I just meant if he is anew let he start with some tutorial sites.

Comment: Just had to: http://www.w3fools.com/ LOL